# Как спарсить текст из html тега без текста его дочерних элементов?

Tags: php, html, парсер

Использую библиотеку hquery для php. Легко встала на ларавел. Так вот там есть все методы, кроме нормального парсинга текста между тегов.

```
<div>
  <h1>Bot in Telegram.</h1>
  Bot
  <p>The noise-causing <b>neural</b> network.</p>
  in Telegram
</div>
```

Ответом должна быть строка: "Bot in Telegram". Вот пример кода, из которого надо парсить, теги могут быть разными, как и их количество. Возможно ли как то спарсить при имеющемся раскладе?

Comment: И как вы пытались это сделать?.. [hQuery github](https://github.com/duzun/hQuery.php) - абсолютно всё что вам надо есть сразу на этой странице, и сам документ и `find()`

Comment: Я хочу пройти по всем тегам на странице и спарсить имя тега и текст в нем. И так далее. В hquery есть метод text() , но он возвращает текст из дочерних элементов.